# A replacement for InfoWindow for google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

While developping a map app I was trying to show different InfoWindows for many markers that display information and buttons ,I discovered that InfoWindows have been converted to images or Bitmap so the buttons actually won't be clickable , I tried to find replacement but I only found images but no names, I want to develop something similar but I don't know if it's a custom dialog box or something else ,please tell me what is it ?? Because I need to show them using **onMarkerClick** method.

My question is very simple, how are these two views are called :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UinzK.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idV63.png)